# Infinite primes and notation

Tags: number-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory, rational-numbers

While reading a book about algebraic number theory, the symbol for a rational prime $p$

$$p^\infty$$

often occurs and I was wondering, what the exact definition of this is.
Also, what is the defnition of the field $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$? I expect it to be the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ at an infinite place $\infty$, but that would be $\mathbb{R}$, right? What could it stand for?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct interpretation of $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ as being the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in my case.

Comment: That's somewhat common notation. Usually the context is that you write $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^n})$ for the number field that results by adjoining the $p^n$th roots of unity to $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})$ be the field that results when you adjoin all $p$-power roots of unity to $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ usually denotes the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ within $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})$.

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would help.

Sometimes for an abelian group $A$ we write $A[p^\infty]$ to mean $\bigcup A[p^n]$, i.e. the stuff in $A$ that's killed by some power of $p$. And if that group is the group of roots of unity in an algebraically closed field of characteristic prime to $p$, sometimes this is written $\mu_{p^\infty}$.

Usually $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ would mean $\mathbb{R}$, especially in a context like
$$
{\prod_{p \leq \infty}}^\prime \mathbb{Q}_p
$$
where it always means this. (But I could also see it as the union of a tower of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ named $\mathbb{Q}_1$, $\mathbb{Q}_2$..., although those aren't very good names since they conflict with the terminology for $p$-adics and most people who care about towers of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ also care about $p$-adics.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response as always, hunter! I've seen the first notation in cases like you've written, but also in assertions like "Let the degree of a local extension be divisible by $p^\infty$." Does that mean, that a finite degree is arbitrary often divisible by $p$? I can hardly believe that. :-)